# How to get continuous index numbers from nested ForEach loop?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit, swiftui-foreach

I'm using a 4-block grid for my Widget Extension.

I want to populate these grids with an array of elements.

```swift
let exampleArray = ["test1","test2","test3","test4"]
```

When I use two nested ForEach loops, I can't get the element in the 4th index.

```swift
VStack {
    ForEach((0..<2)) { column in
        HStack {
            ForEach((0..<2)) { index in
                ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                    Text(newsList[(index+column)])  // 0+0, 1+0, 0+1, 1+1
                    // Text = test1, test2, test2, test3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any way I can work around this? Because it's in `View`, I can't use any operations.

Full code of the View:

```
struct AppWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily)
    var widgetFamily

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 6) {
            Image("logo")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            if widgetFamily == .systemLarge {
                VStack {
                ForEach((0..<2)) { column in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach((0..<2)) { index in
                            ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                                if let url = URL(string: imageList[(index+column)]), let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
                                let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                    .centerCropped()
                                    .frame(maxHeight: 150, alignment: .center)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                            .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                                            .shadow(radius: 10)
                                } else {
                                    Image("ph_background")
                                        .centerCropped()
                                        .frame(maxHeight: 150, alignment: .center)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                                }
                                
                                Text(newsList[(index+column)])
                                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .fontWeight(.light)
                                    // .frame(maxHeight: 50)
                                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.black).blur(radius: 20))
                                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                                    .padding(.top, 5)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution**
Please check the accepted answer.

```swift
struct AppWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily)
    var widgetFamily

    var body: some View {
        var columns: [GridItem] =
                 Array(repeating: .init(.fixed(100)), count: 2)

        if widgetFamily == .systemLarge {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach((0..<4)) { index in
                ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                    if let url = URL(string: imageList[(index)]), let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
                    let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        .centerCropped()
                        .frame(maxHeight: 150, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                    } else {
                        Image("ph_background")
                            .centerCropped()
                            .frame(maxHeight: 150, alignment: .center)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    }
                    
                    Text(newsList[(index)])
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        // .frame(maxHeight: 50)
                        .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.black).blur(radius: 20))
                        .padding(.bottom, 5)
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .padding(.trailing, 5)
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is already answered. You should not edit it after the fact to ask a second question.

Comment: Asked as a separate question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `LazyVGrid`

I feel like you really should be using `LazyVGrid` for this...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid

It works like a `List` but it places each item in a grid of columns.

Using this will solve this problem for you.

### Without `LazyVGrid`

If you really don't want to use a `LazyVGrid` (please use this though). Then the calculation you are using is not correct. The calculation is something like...

```
index = row*numberOfCols + column
```

You can't just use the row as that will only increase the index by 1 per row. But you need to increase the index by the number of columns per row (2 in your case).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used LazyVGrid and it is working as expected. The only issue is now the grid sizes are not automatically set. The default VStack + HStack cell sizes were great, I need to set them but other than that everything is fine!

Comment: @OğuzhanVarsak Great! You should be able to configure the size of the columns using the `GridItem`s that you define for the columns. You can read more about GridItem here... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/griditem

Comment: Hello again! I'm having some issues with LazyVGrid. My LazyVGrid cells push the top view (which is in the same VStack with LazyVGrid) out of the frame. Is there a workaround for this? I couldn't find how can I anchor the top of my view to the frame.

Comment: @OğuzhanVarsak hmm... without seeing the code I'm not sure why that would be the case. Would you be able to add a new question on StackOverflow to show your code and then link it here. I'll take a look. Thanks

Comment: I'll just update the code in here if that's fine? There are not many changes already.

Comment: If it's a new question then it really should be a new question. With StackOverflow each question is a single problem/answer. If you're having a different issue now then it would be following the guidelines of StackOverflow to create a new question to ask it.